# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: Jupiter Notebook on Mac First Use

Tags: python, macos, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I have just downloaded Anaconda and am using Jupyter Notebook to complete an assignment. The very basic first assignment involves creating a working directory with the following code:

```
directory_path = r'C:'
os.chdir(directory_path)
```

I have most definitely selected the correct file path for this particular file (used file to copy pathname and pasted into Jupyter notebook; however still receive this error
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: Jupiter Notebook` on Mac First Use
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There is no `C:` drive on a Mac... that's a Windows path.

Answer (score 0):

on your jupyter notebook

```
Import os
os.getcwd()
```

this will get your current path on the jupyter notebook

On your mac,
select any folder you want to be used as a working directory, click the folder info and get pathname i.e (/Users/username/Desktop/Old Data/UDEMY/Credit Risk Modeling/Section 1)

on your jupyter notebook

```
os.chdir("Users/username/Desktop/Old Data/UDEMY/Credit Risk Modeling/Section 1")
```